# Why do Mathematicians use $u$ and $v$ as variables?

Tags: notation, math-history

I'm sure this has happened to you as well: you are reading some hand-written work, the variables used are $u$ and $v$, and at some point the handwriting becomes unclear and you cannot distinguish the $u$s and $v$s at all. This happens to me quite often --- even distinguishing them when they are typeset can sometimes be irritating.

Is there any particular reason, perhaps historical or traditional, why the two most similar-looking letters in the Western alphabet are also one of the most frequently used pairs of variables?

Comment: Not to mention that we also have $\nu$!

Comment: And $\upsilon$, while you're at it! :) (For those not in the know, that's upsilon. Who nu?)

Comment: I have always thought that $\upsilon$ not $\epsilon$ should be used for error.  When you make a mistake: Oopsilon!

Comment: My first year prof had invented the unified letter: $i,\iota,j,e,l,1,r,v,u,\upsilon,\nu,n,m,w,\omega$ all looked virtually indistinguishable on the blackboard.

Comment: The reason is of course historical: When $x$ was introduced as unknown (I once knew where that occured first) and then $y$ and $z$ as natural candidates for the next unknowns/variables, it turned out to be necessary to step back a bit for the next unkowns $u,v,w$. And traditionally from this there is the association $x\leftrightarrow u$, $y\leftrightarrow v$, $w\leftrightarrow z$, e.g. from 3D vector algebra or complex ananlysis ($z=x+iy\mapsto w=u+iv$).

Comment: I think the most common occurrence of $u$ and $v$ together (at least in my experience) is in the context of velocities. In that case, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are already taken to be positions in space, so it becomes natural to use $u$, $v$ and $w$ to represent the corresponding velocities I guess.

Comment: We should advocate the use of $\Xi$ as a variable name. But not $\xi$ which resembles $\zeta$ and/or $3$ esp. in sloppy handwriting. At the other end of the spectrum, if you want to be cruel to your readers, introduce both $\mathfrak S$ and $\mathfrak G$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Descartes used $x$ and $y$ (and also $z$), whereas Viète had used $A$, $E$ and the other vowels.

Comment: Since they are the most similar letters :)

Comment: Adam Ries and the Rechenmeister at that time used as notation for the main variable of a computation a combination of the letters c and o, for cosa, (Coss was a common, Ding as in Dingrechnung a proposed name for algebra). The point being that the combination co or oc or some vertical variant looked very much like a written letter $\mathcal X$ or $\mathfrak X$. This cosa-X was also used alongside the common letter x for some time,... See the nice books with manuscript reproductions by Florian Cajori.

Comment: Just to make it more confusing: The use of the letters u and v traded places between roman-latin and modern-latin. In the old manuscripts one finds "univers." (for "grouping contains all of the following terms) often written as "vniuers."

Comment: Personally, I distinguish $u$ from $v$ by emphasizing its tail.